# Embedded C Serial Communication

Tags: arduino

```
void PrintMessage1(char message[80], int value)
{
 sprintf(str,message,value);
  Serial.print(str);
  Serial.write(13); //carriage return character (ASCII 13, or '\r')
  Serial.write(10); //newline character (ASCII 10, or '\n')
}
```

i got these line but I do not know how to turn the message that is suit the format of sprintf
hope you guys can answer my question.

Comment: I don't even understand your question. "turn the message that is suit the format fo sprinf"??? what do you mean with that.

Comment: If all you’re going to do is print it then why do you think you need to use sprintf to concatenate it?  Just print the two things one after the other.  Printing is buffered. The receiver will not know if you used one print statement on a huge string or printed in pieces.

Comment: Read the [sprintf](http://cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) documentation.